# Is this orange-yellowish-flowered plant a wildflower or a weed?

Tags: identification

Can you please id this flower that grows here and there in my garden:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The zone is 7. All photos are of separate plants.

Comment: A weed is just a plant where you don't want it to be.

Comment: “A weed is but an unloved flower.” 
― Ella Wheeler Wilcox

Comment: its a beautiful flower and I would love to hug it gently :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a California Poppy (national flower of California).

It's used as medicinal plant for various uses. [California Poppy – Health Benefits and Side Effects](https://www.herbal-supplement-resource.com/california-poppy-herb.html)

Answer (score 23):

That is a California poppy, [*Eschscholzia californica*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eschscholzia_californica).  There are various subspecies and cultivars, but the species is certain.

Answer (score 22):

Well, the distinction is really in the eye of the beholder. Since a [wildflower](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildflower) is just a flower that was not intentionally seeded or planted, while a [weed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weed) is defined by being undesirable.

So you like the flower? It's a pretty wildflower. You don't? It's a nasty weed.

Answer (score 2):

It's also called a Welsh poppy.

Comment: I‘m sorry but that’s not a [Welsh poppy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meconopsis_cambrica).